# Get HWID for .NET Reactor

Tags: c#

For some reason i cannot retrieve my HWID using the code specified in the docs for .NET reactor.

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string HardwareID;
            string Hardware;
            Hardware = License.Status.HardwareID;
            HardwareID = License.Status.GetHardwareID(true, true, true, true);
            MessageBox.Show("HWID: " + Hardware);
```

I am doing this but all it's returning is ####.####.####.####.

So if anyone can point me in the right direction id be grateful

Answer (score 3):

You get the hardware ID only after you have protected your software.

The SDK library License.dll is only a dummy assembly which doesn't contain real licensing and hardware ID code. The only purpose of  License.dll is to make references in your compiled software. Then at protection time .NET Reactor replaces the references and injects the real code.

That's the reason why it works only correctly after protection.